# Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) Check the render method of `App`

Tags: react-native, expo

I am facing the below Error I don't have any idea why I am getting it please help!

Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

```
Check the render method of `App`.
```

following is my app.js file

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";

import navigationTheme from "./app/navigation/navigationTheme";
import AppNavigator from "./app/navigation/AppNavigator";
import OfflineNotice from "./app/components/OfflineNotice";
import AuthNavigator from "./app/navigation/AuthNavigator";
import AuthContext from "./app/auth/context";
import authStorage from "./app/auth/storage";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const restoreUser = async () => {
    const user = await authStorage.getUser();
    if (user) setUser(user);
  };

  if (!isReady)
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={restoreUser} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} />
    );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <OfflineNotice />
      <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
        {user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtlpM.png)

Comment: Try adding a double negation before user ```{!!user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}```.

Comment: double negation not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

As the other guy replied before me, add double negation but not as he described, use my example instead.

```
 if (!isReady)
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={restoreUser} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} />
```

and make it like this :

```
if (!!isReady)
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={restoreUser} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} />
```

Please let me know if that fixed the error.

Thanks.